# getting error in EJS file while running res.render

Tags: node.js, syntax, ejs

getting this error:
missing ) after argument list in C:\Users\yoniy\Desktop\YelpCamp\views\campgrounds\index.ejs while compiling ejs

and it's the index.ejs file :

```html
<!-- <%- include "../partials/header" %>  -->

     <header class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container">
             <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tent"></span> Welcome To YelpCamp!</h1>
             <p>View campgrounds from all over the world</p>
             <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/campgrounds/new">Add New Campground</a>
             </p>
              <p>
              <form action="/campgrounds" method="GET" class="form-inline" id="campground-search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Campground search..." class="form-control">
                </div>
              </form>
             </p>
         </div>
     </header>
     
     <div class="row text-center flex-wrap" id="campground-grid">
        <%- campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img src="<%= campground.image %>">
                   <div class="caption">
                       <h4><%= campground.name %></h4>
                   </div>
                   <p>
                       <a href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                   </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <%- }); %>
    </div>

<!-- <%- include "../partials/footer" %> -->
```

can't find the syntax error that I get.
thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use flow control tags `<%` for non output parts of your template. In this case the following lines need to be changed:

```
        <%- campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
```

Should instead be:

```
        <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
```

And this line:

```
        <%- }); %>
```

Should be:

```
        <% }); %>
```

**Update for additional Error**

Your formatting for including additional files is incorrect:

```
<!-- <%- include "../partials/header" %>  -->
```

Should be:

```
<%- include("../partials/header.ejs") %>
```

Same for the footer:

```
<!-- <%- include "../partials/footer" %> -->
```

Should be:

```
<%- include("../partials/footer.ejs") %>
```

Though I cannot validate your paths are correct as I do not know your directory structure.

Comment: thanks!
getting this error now:
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in C:\Users\yoniy\Desktop\YelpCamp\views\campgrounds\index.ejs while compiling ejs